# How to get the Activity.class of an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a method which has a parameter of type `Intent`. I need to get the `Activity.class` from the intent provided (not the String value).

I looked through stackoverflow but only got solutions which return the String value of the class name. Below is a snippet for further clarification.

```
public void myMethod(Intent intent) {

  Class classDef = ;// here I need the MyActivity.class of the code below this method

}


Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
myMethod(intent);
```

I hope you can help me out :-) I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the class name of a Java class, use `Class.forName()` to get the `Class` object for that class. This is standard Java, not specific to Android.